# Create a multiboot USB drive with Ubuntu and Windows 7 using ISO images

Tags: usb, multi-boot, iso-image

I would like to have a bootable USB drive with some bootable ISO images on it, where some sort of menu appears on boot to select a specific image file on the USB drive and continue boot from that one.

Is there a way to create that? I am interested in e.g. Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know how Windows will work, but must they be ISOs specifically? VHDs could probably work.

Comment: Windows 7 does not support being booted from a flash device.  The Enterprise version of Windows 8 will support a portable live operating system type booting feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah, you can try yumi: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

if you have not tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try SARDU. It has a nice user interface and the only thing you have to do is put all your ISO files to a defined folder work the right .

http://www.sarducd.it/

Don't forget to visit the tutorial section of the site to make yourself familiar with the whole procedure.