# how to boot multiple iso's from usb

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, dvd, iso-image

I want to boot multiple ISO images from an external drive what is the best way to do this?

The reason for this is Windows restoration discs. I want to create an .ISO file of each of the recovery DVD's (can be up to 12 discs) and then boot from the USB device to recovery the computer so I don't have to use the DVD's every time I want a recovery.

I'm guessing there will have to be some way to mount each .ISO file when the next disc is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple live CD ISO images on a single USB drive](http://superuser.com/questions/26548/multiple-live-cd-iso-images-on-a-single-usb-drive), http://superuser.com/questions/416786/create-a-multiboot-usb-drive-with-ubuntu-and-windows-7-using-iso-images

Comment: @techie007 no this is a completely different question I know how to create a USB which boots multiple live distros or ISO's. I want to create a USB install where the installation comes from multiple ISO's not just one.